# Addition transactionSettings to a request object on Authorize.net (using sdk-python)

Tags: python, authorize.net, pyxb

I am using Authorize.net's native [python sdk](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-python). In their [API documentation](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html), it shows that you can nest a setting as follows:

```
transactionSettings
    setting
        settingName
        settingValue
```

I have setup a `ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest` object, and am trying to set `duplicateWindow` to `False`.

```
request = apicontractsv1.ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest()
request.transactionSettings = {'setting': [{'settingName': 'duplicateWindow', 'settingValue': False}] }
```

That seems to have no impact.

What I am trying to do is override Authorize.net's default protection for duplicate transactions because I need to be able to submit multiple subscriptions for a single user.

**Any thoughts on how to:**

**(1) properly set `transactionSettings` and/or**

**(2) override duplication error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this is that I had the list and dictionaries set incorrectly. Unfortunately, it took a lot of digging thru source code to figure this out because the documentation was not as clear as I would have hoped. Regardless, now that I found the solution, all is well:

```
request.transactionSettings = [{'setting': {'settingName': 'duplicateWindow', 'settingValue': False} }]
```

Comment: I get this...    raise pyxb.SimpleTypeValueError(cls, value)
pyxb.exceptions_.SimpleTypeValueError: Type {AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema
.xsd}ArrayOfSetting cannot be created from: [{'setting': {'settingValue': False,
 'settingName': 'duplicateWindow'}}] ... any ideas?

Comment: Sorry. This project is so long ago I barely remember doing it. Maybe someone else does.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the duplicate window protection you need to set it to zero:

```
request = apicontractsv1.ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest()
request.transactionSettings = {'setting': [{'settingName': 'duplicateWindow', 'settingValue': 0}] }
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that before with no impact. I tried `False`, `None`, `0` and the inverse of all just to see if there was an impact. Perhaps I need to instantiate a settings object.